# How to map numeric(13, 3)[] database column to Hibernate entity field?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

We have a use case where there exists a column `'datewise_tariff'` of type `numeric(13,3)[]` in Postgres database. Values stored with this column are decimal values like `{953.893,953.893,953.893}`

We need to map this column type to a Hibernate Java Entity but we are getting the below error:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
ERROR: column "datewise_tariff" is of type numeric[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 738
```

We tried mapping it via:

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff")
private float[] datewiseTariff
```

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff")
private BigDecimal[] datewiseTariff
```

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff", columnDefinition = "numeric(13,3)[]")
private float[] datewiseTariff;
```

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff", columnDefinition = "numeric(13,3)[]")
private BigDecimal[] datewiseTariff;
```

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff", columnDefinition = "numeric(13,3)[]")
private byte[] datewiseTariff;
```

```
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff")
private byte[] datewiseTariff;
```

All above methods seems to be not working and always throws the same above error.
Also, tried using `hibernate-types` sdk but it seems that it also doesn't have support for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an unending era of hit and trial and diving into the ocean of Hibernate documentation, Finally, found a way to do it. `@ColumnTransformer` came to the rescue.

Usage as follows:

```
@Type(type = "list-array")
@Column(name = "datewise_tariff")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::numeric(13,3)[]", read = "?::float[]")
private List<Double> datewiseTariff;
```

`list-array` is defined using `hibernate-types` library.

```
@TypeDef(name = "list-array", typeClass = ListArrayType.class)
```